# How to send a parameter from java script function to a servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I want to send some parameters to a servlet with the help of javascript..... 
In my jsp page there is a parameter "a[j]" which is generated dynamically and on a click the javascript function invoke and this a[j] parameter which is "ur" in java script function should be send to a servlet named Rank.....
Tell me which function should i use to forward the parameter...

IN Jsp:

```
<a href="<%out.println(a[j]);%>" onclick="(rank('<%=a[j]%>'))"><%out.println(a[j+1]);%></a>
```

Javascript:(rank)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function rank(ur)
    { ??????????("Rank?set="+ur);

    }
    </script>
```

In Servlet(Rank):

```
String s = (String)request.getParameter("set");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
window.location="Rank?set="+ur;
```

or

```
document.body.innerHTML+='<form id="myform" action="Rank" method="get"><input name="set" value="'+ur+'" /></form>';
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

**Edit**:

Ah, I think that what you need is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), a group of interrelated web development techniques used on the client-side to create asynchronous web applications. With Ajax, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

Then the code is:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    //only if you want the response
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","Rank?set=" + ur,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: The above code is not working........actually, i want to update my database on click event.....When i  use window.open("Rank?set="+ur);
then my db gets updated but another window is opening which i don't want....So, i want that my db should be update without the opening of new window...I am giving a link to the Rank servlet:
http://pastebin.com/QiNyZhSy